# Pyqt Hide/Remove QAction Menu from toolbutton

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
self.find_next_ret_act = QtWidgets.QAction(triggered=self.toolButton_5.animateClick)
self.find_next_ret_act.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Return"))
self.find_next_enter_act = QtWidgets.QAction(triggered=self.toolButton_5.animateClick)
self.find_next_enter_act.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Enter"))
self.toolButton_5.addActions([self.find_next_ret_act, self.find_next_enter_act])
```

I am using PyQt5 and I was trying to set couple of shortcuts to one tool button but it didn't work except with the QAction workaround but the problem now is that I want to hide the QAction menu that appears when I hold the tool button down, is there any way to do so?

Thanks,

Max

Comment: Don't use `QAction`, use [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html).

Comment: Can you provide to me an example, please?

Comment: `self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Return"), self.toolButton_5, self.toolButton_5.animateClick)`.

Comment: Works, Thanks alot